# IE8cv puzzler: setting zoom:1 via class hides content

Tags: html, html-table, overflow, zooming, haslayout

If the following conditions are met, setting `zoom:1` hides the element's content:

1. Markup must have this structure:

   ```
   <table><tr><td>
       <div class="overflow">
           <span class="zoom">zoom</span>
       </div>
   </td></tr></table>
   ```
2. These styles must be defined:

   ```
   .somethingSPECIAL .zoom {
       zoom: 1;
   }
   .overflow {
       width: 300px;  /* Whatever px here. */
       height: 150px; /* Whatever px here. */
       overflow: auto;
   }
   ```
3. The `somethingSPECIAL` class should be applied to any ancestor of the markup above *after* page load (like on a button click).
4. The browser you've been forced to use must be IE8 in Compatibility View.

[Here's a live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/GgY6C/5/)

Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent it?  (I can't get rid of `zoom: 1`.  I also have to set the parent class as shown in the demo.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the width and height of the span element went from 33x19 to 0x0. So if you set it back to 'auto' it works.

```
$('.zoom').css('width', 'auto');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GgY6C/29/

Comment: That's redonkulous, but it works.  Thanks!  Any theories on why IE8CV does this?

Comment: Also, I guess just resetting the `span`s class works too, and this won't mess up any spans that might have a width (when they also have display:block).

    `.find('.zoom').addClass('.zoom')`

http://jsfiddle.net/GgY6C/30/

Comment: Whoops!  Missed the typo.  ".zoom" isn't a class and wasn't reapplying zoom:1...  It was just adding a class doing nothing.  This would work too:  `.find('.zoom').addClass('somethingThatDoesntEvenExist')`.  WTF?

http://jsfiddle.net/GgY6C/31/